# Space complexity of Java data structures

Tags: java, algorithm, memory, data-structures, analysis

I have been searching for many websites that contain information of the space complexity of Java data structures. I am searching specifically for the space complexity of the `HashMap`, `ArrayList`, `Stack` and `LinkedList`. One site that I found that came close and had information only on the Stack and LinkedList was: http://bigocheatsheet.com/, but it only had the worst case. Would any one know of any other sources that have information on the space complexity of the HashMap or ArrayList, preferably average case and worst case?

Comment: I dont understand your question. Space or time complexity is attached to an operation like searching an element. There is no space complexity of Hashmap.

Comment: http://java-performance.info/memory-consumption-of-java-data-types-1/ might be worth a look

Comment: Correct typo in question title. Turned URL into clickable link. Used actual class names for references to data structures. Some minor grammar fixes.

Comment: @Lokesh: There is space complexity in `HashMap`, even if it is linear in the number of entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all `O(N)` in space usage under normal conditions.  (So are all of the standard collection data structures, I think ...)

Of course, that doesn't tell you some important facts about how much space these data structures will use in practice.  For example:

- An `ArrayList` or `HashMap`s space usage is not directly proportional to the list size.  Both have a "double the size when full" strategy for some or all of their space utilization.
- In the best case, an `ArrayList` uses less space per element than a `LinkedList`, and a `LinkedList` uses less space per element than a `HashMap`.

And so on.

It is also difficult to quantify the worst case ... because there are certain usage patterns that can lead to an **empty** `ArrayList` or `HashMap` occupying a large amount of space.  For these data structures, the space usage *may be* proportional to the maximum `N` value (so far) not the current `N` value.

- An `ArrayList` does not "give back" space when elements are removed.
- With a `HashMap` the space occupied by the chains can grow and shrink, but the hash array only grows.

Comment: @greybeard - the tree it will have `N` nodes int total. All tree nodes refer directly to a unique element of the tree ... there is no distinction between internal and leaf nodes.  Note: we are not accounting the space used to store the elements (or keys) themselves because that is the same for all `Collection` based data structures.

Comment: Ooops ... no TreeMap is O(N) in space.  Correcting that.  Thanks.

Comment: I think the word of warning about `HashMap`s after removals to the point. With `ArrayList`, there's `trimToSize()`.

Comment: Yes, but `trimToSize()` is `O(N)` time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the code for these classes, you can see that they are internally represented as arrays. Hence the complexity of operations should be similar to those on arrays.